# Objective-C access int from other class

Tags: objective-c, class, integer

I know this question has been asked a lot but I'm new to Objective-C.
My code in the first viewcontroller.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic) int mutecounter;
@property (nonatomic) ViewController *targetLevelController;
@end
```

My code in the first viewcontroller in the .m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize mutecounter;
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *musicFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Ambler" withExtension:@"mp3"];
    self.backgroundMusic = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];
    self.backgroundMusic.numberOfLoops = -1;
    self.backgroundMusic.volume = 0.3;
    [self.backgroundMusic play];
    [self.muteButtonOutlet setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mutebutton.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    _targetLevelController=[[ViewController alloc]init];
    _targetLevelController.mutecounter = mutecounter;
}
- (IBAction)muteButton:(id)sender {
    if (mutecounter % 2 == 0){
        self.backgroundMusic.volume = 0;
        mutecounter = mutecounter + 1;
        [self.muteButtonOutlet setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unmutebutton.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        self.backgroundMusic.volume = 0.3;
        mutecounter = mutecounter + 1;
        [self.muteButtonOutlet setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mutebutton.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

And my code in the second Viewcontroller.h:

```
@interface LevelController : UIViewController
- (IBAction)muteButton:(id)sender;
@end
```

and my code in the second Viewcontroller.m

```
#import "LevelController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface LevelController ()

@end
@implementation LevelController
int mutecounter2;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *musicFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Ambler" withExtension:@"mp3"];
    self.backgroundMusic = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];
    self.backgroundMusic.numberOfLoops = -1;
    self.backgroundMusic.volume = 0.3;
    [self.backgroundMusic play];
    ViewController *targetLevelController=[[ViewController alloc]init];
    mutecounter2 = targetLevelController.mutecounter;
    if (mutecounter2 % 2 == 0){
        self.backgroundMusic.volume = 0;
        [self.muteButtonOutlet setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mutebutton.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        self.backgroundMusic.volume = 0.3;
        [self.muteButtonOutlet setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unmutebutton.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}

- (IBAction)muteButton:(id)sender {
    if (mutecounter2 % 2 == 0){
        self.backgroundMusic.volume = 0;
        mutecounter2 = mutecounter2 + 1;
        [self.muteButtonOutlet setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unmutebutton.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        self.backgroundMusic.volume = 0.3;
        mutecounter2 = mutecounter2 + 1;
        [self.muteButtonOutlet setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mutebutton.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    }

}
```

The problem is that the code isn't working.
Could someone help me?
I always get the value 0 in mutecounter2.
But it should be 1 or 2 or 3 or something.
Thanks Matis

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lots of issues here.  I'd suggest revisiting some of the guides that discuss application architecture.  mutecounter2 is not an instance variable, for example, but it probably shouldn't exist at all.

If the mute count is global state in your application, probably the easiest place to store it is in your application's delegate.  Add a the muteCounter @property to the delegate and both view controllers can get to it.

However, if your 2nd view controller is always pushed by the first, then the first can set the value on the second prior to the push.   Thus is also common.

Unless that muteCounter is supposed to be persisted across app launches, do not use NSUserDefaults.

---

Thinking this through a bit more, it seems like @MatisDS should likely use a shared instance that manages the background music, including containment of the mute counter, etc... While shared instances are generally discouraged, there are cases where it is warranted and this would seem to be one of them in that you are only going to have one background piece of music playing and it would likely need to be globally managed.

While Peter Hosey's suggestion of using a global variable is quite valid, there seems to be enough logic related to the management of said variable that encapsulating that functionality into a single spot would save code and be simpler.

Comment: Thx for your answer I haven't coded anything in the delegate file. Could you please explain why delegate is used for?

Comment: I would suggest that you start here and gain a firm understanding of iOS app design patterns.  You should really know about the app delegate by this point. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: @MatisDS: In addition to the document bbum suggested, you should also read “Programming with Objective-C”, which will cover things like how to declare instance variables. You'll also learn why you don't need to declare an instance variable or use `@synthesize` (much less both) for this. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/

Comment: I disagree that storing global state in the application's delegate is any better than storing it in global variables. All that does is make the access expressions longer. Better to abolish global state entirely; *if* that isn't an option, then the least-bad solution is to put it in one or more well-defined singletons that you can bulldoze at the earliest opportunity.

Comment: @MatisDS Because `NSUserDefaults` isn't intended to be a workaround for poorly architected applications.  Do you really want `mutecounter` to be persisted between runs of your application?  If the answer is "No, it should always start with a value of 0", then NSUserDefaults is the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I always get the value 0 in mutecounter2. But it should be 1 or 2 or 3
>   or something.

Well...

```
ViewController *targetLevelController=[[ViewController alloc]init];
mutecounter2 = targetLevelController.mutecounter;
```

You're initializing a ViewController instance. That has a mutecounter property, but you're not initializing it anywhere. So mutecounter2 is 0.

```
if (mutecounter2 % 2 == 0){
    self.backgroundMusic.volume = 0;
    mutecounter2 = mutecounter2;
    [self.muteButtonOutlet setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mutebutton.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

You enter that conditional block because 0 % 2 = 0. You set the volume property to 0, then mutecounter2 to itself, so it is still 0 (this line should be deleted, it's doing nothing at all).

So to take a step back, I'm wondering if you even need 2 View Controllers here? While the concept of parent/child view controllers is possible as of iOS 5, they are even easier to implement in iOS 6 via Embed Segues in a Storyboard. It seems like you're just starting out so I'd recommend using Storyboards to get going. Apple provides a few Storyboard tutorials in their documentation.

If you really do need two View Controllers, you'd typically pass data like this to the View Controller directly like:

```
ViewController *newVC = [[ViewController alloc] init]
newVC.propertyName = someValue
```

But you've got the reverse, so it looks like you're trying to "pull" a value from another VC instead of having one pushed. Don't do it that way, because then your VCs have unnecessary dependencies.

But really, use Storyboards.

Comment: I'm new to Objective-C and I think I am using storyboards? In xcode I have a mainstoryboard.storyboard file so I think I use storyboards.

Comment: `mutecounter2` isn't related to the `mutecounter` property. It's a global variable declared within the `@implementation`. (I think the questioner meant to declare an instance variable, not that it would make any real difference.)

Comment: @MatisDS yes, sounds like you are using storyboards then, but I'm not sure how well you're embracing them. Typically the way you would pass data from one VC to another is by providing an implementation for the first VC's prepareForSegue: method. Read that "Your first iOS application" tutorial that Apple provides for more.